# Update : I get sum of products and total cost but it's not updating when quantity updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get the  sum of products and over all cost but i want to update when item quantity changes

```
.filter('total', function () {
    return function (input, property) {
        var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0;
        if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
            return i;
        } else if (isNaN(input[0][property])) {
            throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
        } else {
            var total = 0;
            while (i--)
                total += input[i][property];
            return total;
        }
    };
})
```

And

```
<div>{{ data|total }} items</div>
            <div>{{ data|total:'price' }}</div>
```

[**DEMO FOR UPDATED PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/4OtvS9/preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally I got it using Filters in angularjs...

```
//code for getting total number of products
    .filter('total', function () {
        return function (input, property) {
            var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0;
            if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
                return i;
            } else if (isNaN(input[0][property])) {
                throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
            } else {
                var total = 0;
                while (i--)
                    total += input[i][property];
                return total;
            }
        };
    })


//to print the total
     <div>{{ data|total }} items</div>


//to get the overall cost when you update item in quantity
 $scope.total = function () {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item) {
            total += item.quan * item.price;
        })

        return total;
    }


// to print the overall total
<div>new total{{total()}}</div>
```

**[Updated Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/4OtvS9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
Change  total to total: {{ getTotal() }} in your template
```

Controller

```
$scope.getTotal = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.items.length; i++){
       var item = $scope.cart.items[i];
       total += (item.price * item.quantity);
    }
    return total;
}

.filter('total', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return function (input, property) {
    var i = input instanceof Array ? input.length : 0,
        p = $parse(property);

    if (typeof property === 'undefined' || i === 0) {
        return i;
    } else if (isNaN(p(input[0]))) {
        throw 'filter total can count only numeric values';
    } else {
        var total = 0;
        while (i--)
            total += p(input[i]);
        return total;
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: No .. its not updating @Nitin_Rajan

Answer (score 0):

Your products seem to be stored in `$scope.todos`, since that's what you're iterating on in the ng-repeat. But your loop to compute the total iterates on `$scope.item`.

It should be

```
angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (item) {
```